# Remove every word of after a bracket and append remaining words to Python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to remove every word of after a bracket (including bracket) in a line of string and append remaining words to Python list.

```
s = "[AA BB, CC, DD, EE] [PP QQ, RR] [WW XX, YY, ZZ]"
```

Expected result:

```
list =['BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'QQ', 'RR', 'XX', 'YY', 'ZZ']
```

I have tried using below lines of code where keyword include '[' and ' '

```
befor_keyowrd, keyword, after_keyword = mystring.partition('keyword')
list.append(after_keyword)
```

Comment: If you include some code that you have already tried you are far more likely to get an answer. As it stands now this question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
s = "[AA BB, CC, DD, EE] [PP QQ, RR] [WW XX, YY, ZZ]"
response = re.findall('(?<![[\w])\w+', s)
```

Comment: Can anyone give me a link to the documents that shows some examples for python regular expressions? The https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html does explain the REGEXs but would like to see many examples on these

Comment: Python regexes: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
Best website IMO to learn them: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @juggernaut How about you learn more about [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).  Everything you need to know about how to use the module is in the documentation on the python site.  Everything you need to know about regular expressions is found on their doc site.

Comment: @ZWiki : What if I want to retain the square brackets and remove only the first word after square bracket ? What modification should be done?

Comment: `a = re.sub(r'(?<=\[)[\w]+[^\w]+', '', s)`. In this example, a would become the string `[BB, CC, DD, EE] [QQ, RR] [XX, YY, ZZ]`